# Juju deployed apache+gunicorn+django app over SSL, openid fails with No Mode

Tags: python, apache2, proxy, juju

**Blog post**

Just FYI I wrote up a blog post explaining everything I did to get up and going:
http://www.astokes.org/post/2013-07-14-juju-gunicorn-apache-django

I have these services deployed and everything is accessible over https. However, when I attempt to authenticate via launchpad.net openid 2 things happen.

First the callback address is http://10.x.x.x when it should be https://10.x.x.x and second the application fails with a **OpenID authentication failed: Invalid openid.mode ''"** when it finally does make it back to the https host.

**zef-sample-apache2-0:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/10.0.3.206_https**

```
# Managed by juju
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      10.0.3.206
    Redirect permanent / https://10.0.3.206/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName      10.0.3.206
    ServerAdmin     cts@canonical.com

    CustomLog       /var/log/cts-custom.log combined
    ErrorLog        /var/log/cts-error.log


    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-cts.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-cts.key
    RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-SSL "on"
    RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED_PROTO "https"

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    <Proxy *>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.3.113:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.3.113:8080/

    #RewriteEngine on

    #RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://10.0.3.113:8080/$1 [P,L]

#    Alias           /favicon.ico    /srv/seg-dashboard/segdash/static/favicon.ico
#    Alias           /robots.txt     /srv/seg-dashboard/segdash/static/robots.txt
#    Alias           /static/admin    /var/www/static/admin
#    Alias           /static/        /srv/seg-dashboard/segdash/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

I force everything over ssl so at this point im not sure if its an application issue with my django app since running a local https server and authenticating over SSL works fine.

Any ideas?

Here is my juju status output

```
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: local
    instance-state: running
services:
  apache2:
    charm: cs:precise/apache2-11
    exposed: true
    relations:
      reverseproxy:
      - seg-dashboard
    units:
      apache2/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 0
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: 10.0.3.206
  gunicorn:
    charm: cs:precise/gunicorn-7
    relations:
      wsgi-file:
      - seg-dashboard
    subordinate: true
    subordinate-to:
    - seg-dashboard
  postgresql:
    charm: cs:precise/postgresql-30
    exposed: false
    relations:
      db:
      - seg-dashboard
      replication:
      - postgresql
    units:
      postgresql/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 0
        public-address: 10.0.3.37
  rabbitmq-server:
    charm: cs:precise/rabbitmq-server-12
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - seg-dashboard
      cluster:
      - rabbitmq-server
    units:
      rabbitmq-server/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 0
        public-address: 10.0.3.144
  seg-dashboard:
    charm: local:precise/seg-dashboard-1
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      db:
      - postgresql
      website:
      - apache2
      wsgi:
      - gunicorn
    units:
      seg-dashboard/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 0
        public-address: 10.0.3.113
        subordinates:
          gunicorn/0:
            agent-state: started
```

And here is the relevant portion to the Launchpad Openid setup (django settings.py)

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_EXTERNAL_OPENID_REDIRECT_DOMAINS = ['lvh.me', 'localhost', 'canonical.com']

# Add support for django-openid-auth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_openid_auth.auth.OpenIDBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

OPENID_CREATE_USERS = True
OPENID_UPDATE_DETAILS_FROM_SREG = True
OPENID_SSO_SERVER_URL = 'https://login.launchpad.net/'
OPENID_USE_AS_ADMIN_LOGIN = True
OPENID_LAUNCHPAD_TEAMS_REQUIRED = [
    'canonical',
]
OPENID_LAUNCHPAD_STAFF_TEAMS = (
    'cool-guys',
)
OPENID_STRICT_USERNAMES = True
OPENID_USE_EMAIL_FOR_USERNAME = True

LOGIN_URL = '/openid/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Login is required for all these patterns
LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS = (
    r'/(.*)$',
)
# We much except the openid URLs otherwise we go in loops.
LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS = (
    r'/openid/(.*)$',
)
```

Additional:

I believe the problem stems from the handoff from Apache(SSL) to gunicorn(nonSSL) and then when it hits launchpad.net the callback url is the Apache server (nonSSL). I attempted to use something like django-sslify to force SSL on the application side but it seems like the ProxyPreserveHost does not care/check if the host is coming from https or http and just defaults to http.

More:

Here is the request headers sent to launchpad.net

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Referer:https://10.0.3.218/openid/login/?next=/
Host:login.launchpad.net
DNT:1
Connection:keep-alive
```

And here is what the form data looks like:

```
openid_referer:"https://10.0.3.218/openid/login/?next=/"
openid.return_to:http://10.0.3.218/openid/complete/?next=%2F&janrain_nonce=2013-07-13T03%3A35%3A28ZSrfuV5
openid.realm:http://10.0.3.218/
```

This is utilizing the django-openid-auth library and I am currently digging through the code to see why the consumer is directly setting the return_to http when the referer shows https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive updated the post to show the proper configuration in both an Apache vhost and the django settings.py file.

You'll want to see a header to something like

RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED_PROTO "https"

And set the following in django settings

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWADED_PROTO', 'https')

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER